# img get oversize windows

Tags: html, image, css

Please have a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jkkhh/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head> 
    <style>
        body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
        div { height: 100%; width: 100%; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; background: black;}
        img { height: 100%;}
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div><img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/85/Smiley.svg'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Even setting height 100% for both  and , there still has little extra space in the bottom that causes the scrollbar. Does anyone know what causes that space?

I just want to know the behavior.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `img` tag is an inline tag and the extra space you're seeing is due to this. Add `display:block` to the style of the image.